# Change click event of a clickable div inside another div on changing opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the HTML structure as follows:

```
<div class="boxes workshops wrapl">
    <a href="#" id="showw1" class="workshops-button lfloat">Show it</a>
</div>

<div class="boxes exhibitions">
    <a href="#" id="showex1" class="exhibitions-button lfloat">Show it</a>
</div> 
<div class="boxes gallery">
    <a href="#" id="showex1" class="gallery-button lfloat">Show it</a>
</div>
```

The class `.boxes` are squares set next to one another. There are about 30 boxes. Initially all the boxes are set to `opacity:1` and all the `-button` class are set at `opacity:0`.

However, then also if I hover my mouse inside the .boxes, the links are clickable.

[My code is here on Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prateeksachan/qGpML/)

If you see the Jsfiddle, I'm still able to `click` for the `.boxes` that have faded out or when I'm currently present in `home` state.

**EDIT # 1**
Here are the relevant codes:

[HTML code](http://dpaste.com/865902/)

[Javascript code](http://dpaste.com/865899/)

[CSS Code](http://dpaste.com/865903/)

Comment: I can't see the CSS on JSFiddle, or the JavaScript for that matter.

Comment: I think you're having some major float issues....the JSFiddle you posted has some links outside the boxes.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: The code is there. All the HTML ,CSS, and Javascript ones.

Comment: @Bagavatu: Don't care about the floating issue. It has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @xan, I can see the output, but I cannot see the code. :(

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: I guess Jsfiddle is behaving strangely. Right click on the Jsfiddle page, and click on "Reload". Anyways, I've included all the code in the question also. See the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/qGpML/5/

```
var isHome = true;
    $(function () {
$('.boxes').find('a').hide();
        $("#navi a").click(function() {
            c = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
           $('.boxes').find('a').show();
            isHome = c=="home";
            if (isHome){
                $('.events-button, .workshops-button, .gallery-button, .sponsors-button, .hospitality-button, .lectures-button, .exhibitions-button').animate({opacity:0.0},500);
                $('.boxes').find('a').hide();
                $(".boxes").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 500 );

            } else {
                $('.' + c).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 500 );
                $('.' + c + "-button").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 500 ).addClass('activehack');
                $('.activehack').not('.' + c + "-button").animate({opacity: 0.0}, 500 );
                $('.boxes').not('.' + c).animate({opacity: 0.3}, 500 );
        $('.boxes').not('.' + c ).find('a').hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: That works. Though, still a minor issue. If you click `events` and then `home`, they are again clickable.

Comment: Just add this line in `if(isHome){..`:
`$('.boxes').find('a').hide();`

Comment: Yes great.. I was about to update it.. and updated now.. Anyway Happy to be Helpful.. :)